# css background not working on ios browsers

Tags: ios, css

My site, which you can find [here](http://testlocation.skyrun.com), has on the top menu a 65% opaque div under the menu and logo to help the logo and menu stand out.

It works on any browser on PC and Android.

It does not work on any browser on any iOS device... (logo and menu displays without the opaque background).

My css is:

```
.tm-navbar-transparent:not(.tm-navbar-slide) .tm-navbar {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
};
```

Comment: Try to add in your css: -webkit-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) instead of only background.

Answer (score 1):

The way you target your style is a bit complicated. not sure sure ios supports 'not'... just give the div a class or an id and target that with css.

Add an id to your bar in html:

```
<div id='topbar' class='tm-navbar uk-navbar'> ... your topbar ... </div>
```

then in css

```
#topbar {  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65); }
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
#topbar {  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) !important; }
```

as there might be some other thing that's targetting it.